# Android Pre Launch Report - Showing crashes but zero issues

Tags: android, google-play-console, prelaunch

For the last two APKs I have uploaded to play console the android pre launch report is showing "Devices with issues 9" under "Stability tab" but then in the individual break down each device has 0 issues. Any explanation to this? Is this APK safe to launch?

[Play console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9cAe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the same report in the new console. It seems some data may differ.

New console: https://play.google.com/console/developers/

Comment: This has indeed solved the "problem". In the new console the issues are not displayed anymore. Thank you!